# javafx: How to bind the Enter key to a button and fire off an event when it is clicked?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically, I have a `okayButton` that sits in a `stage` and when it is clicked , it performs a list of tasks. Now I want to bind the `Enter` key to this button such that **when it is clicked OR the ENTER key is pressed**, it performs a list of tasks.

```
    okayButton.setOnAction(e -> {       
           .........
        }
    });
```

How can I do that ? I have read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758782/fire-buttons-onaction-with-enter-in-javafx) already. However, it did not help me to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: You don't mention if the button should be focused while pressing `Enter` or if it should be a global binding

Comment: What do you mean "focused"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28computing%29

Comment: Can I have an answer for both ?

Comment: If it's focus, just setting an `onAction` handler should work, if it's not... wait a minute

Comment: I am new to javafx. Can you show me both please?  Thanks. 
I am slightly confused. Can I have multiple `setOnAction` for one button?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, set a hanlder on your button :

```
okayButton.setOnAction(e -> {       
       ......
});
```

If the button has the focus, pressing **Enter** will automatically call this handler. Otherwise, you can do this in your `start` method :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      // ...
      Node root = ...;
      setGlobalEventHandler(root);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 0, 0);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
}

private void setGlobalEventHandler(Node root) {
    root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, ev -> {
        if (ev.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
           okayButton.fire();
           ev.consume(); 
        }
    });
}
```

If you have only one button of this kind, you can use the following method instead.

```
okayButton.setDefaultButton(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to perform some action when the button is clicked right ? So just code this action, it's your handler.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your answer. Forget about what I said.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically change the default button property of the currently focused button by using binding

```
btn.defaultButtonProperty().bind(btn.focusedProperty());
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem like mynameisJEFF. (I'm using Windows and as I read here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-June/019234.html it is the SPACE_BAR and not ENTER, which fires a Button in JavaFX) I didn't want to add a listener to every Button, so I registered a Listener to the root node and asked the scene, which node is focused to fire that one. Here is my code (it is xtend, but I think it very easy to understand):

```
override start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    val root = FXTable.createRoot
    val mainScene = new Scene(root)
    root.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, [event|
        if(event.code === KeyCode.ENTER){
            switch(focusedNode : mainScene.focusOwnerProperty.get){
                Button:{
                    focusedNode.fire
                    event.consume
                }
                default:{
                }
            }
        }
    ])
    primaryStage.scene = mainScene
    primaryStage.show
    primaryStage.maximized = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much more simple a standard way to do that using ***setOnKeyPressed***

```
okayButton.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            okayButton.fire();
        }
    }
    );
```

And don't forget that you should define SetOnAction too, other way it's work but it's doing nothing.

```
okayButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        // Do what ever you want to your button do. Like :
        System.Out.Print("Okay Button Fired (Clicked or Pressed");
    }
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
okayButton.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
               System.out.print("Your function call or code can go here");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: the question is about javafx (not awt)