# Javafx: How to bound two functions of one button

Tags: function, javafx

Hellow guys, today I come across another problem.
Here is a part of my code. I've got there 2 functions which I want to be assigned to the one Button (Log In), how can I do that ?

```
@FXML
private void fireLogIn()
{
    LogInButton.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
           if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
             LogIn(event); // <--- there is an error of wrong type of data 
           }
        }); 
}


@FXML
private void LogIn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if(LoginField.getText().equals("MKARK")&&PasswdField.getText().equals("KACZOR1"))
    {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/MainScreen.fxml"));
        Scene MainScene = new Scene(parent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(MainScene);
        stage.show();


    }
    else
    {
        IncorrectDataLink.setVisible(true);
        IncorrectDataLink.setOnAction(e-> openWebpage(uri));    
}

}
```

I want to provide both facilities, pressing the button by mouse or pressing an "ENTER"" botton whenever it's focused on it.

Comment: Why you are giving `event` to `Login` as param?!

Comment: Because it is demanding on me, i guess "private void LogIn(ActionEvent event)"

Comment: Usually an action event is triggered with the enter key too, so why bother and create 2 event handlers?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

1. There is no reason for you to pass in an ActionEvent into the Login method. If you remove the ActionEvent parameter, then you would be able to call `Login` from another event.
2. `LoginButton.fire()` would programmatically click the button, which would then fire the `Login` event. If you add a OnKeyPressedListener to your button, and detect that the 'ENTER' key is clicked, you could programatically click the button rather than having to call the `Login` method again.

Here are some links to help you with detecting an Enter key on a button

[Fire Button's onAction with Enter in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758782/fire-buttons-onaction-with-enter-in-javafx)

[javafx: How to bind the Enter key to a button and fire off an event when it is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038418/javafx-how-to-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-button-and-fire-off-an-event-when-it-is-c)