# How to make all buttons having ActionEvent handler handle Enter key in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have about 50 buttons in my application. For all buttons I created handler this way:

```
@FXML
protected void handleFooButtonActionEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    ...
}
```

This way user can press buttons using mouse left button or Space key. However, it is normal practice (as I know) to allow user press button using Enter key. Is it possible to make all buttons having ActionEvent handler (see above) handle also Enter key in JavaFX, for example if we have reference to `Stage stage`, `Scene scene` or `Parent root`?

Comment: Do you mean when the button is selected, or all the time?

Comment: @jrtapsell I mean when button has focus and user presses Enter key.

Comment: Is this similar to what you want to do? > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758782/fire-buttons-onaction-with-enter-in-javafx

Comment: The usual standard is for the space key to trigger the focused button, not the enter key; changing that might be confusing to users. If you really want to use the enter key you need a key event handler on each button. Probably the best bet would be to subclass button and register the key handler in the constructor. But I would not recommend changing the standard behavior like that.

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your comment. However, I can't agree with you. I've checked several applications - LibreOffice, FireFox, Ubuntu in all of them Enter can be used to press focus button.

Comment: I'm on a Mac right now, but Enter only seems to trigger the default button. Actually, surprisingly few of my applications actually have buttons that accept keyboard input (which is an interesting trend...); they tend to use link-like controls which can't get focus and mnemonics as keyboard shortcuts to them. Firefox definitely responds to the Space bar to trigger a focused button (on my Mac).

Comment: @James_D I use Ubuntu. In Ubuntu FireFox responds both to Space and Enter. Maybe it is somehow linked to OS.

Comment: Anyway... The default key bindings for `Button` are buried pretty deep in private API, and hard-code the key trigger for pressing the button as `SPACE`. They're defined in [`ButtonBehavior`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/ButtonBehavior.java) which is instantiated by `ButtonSkin` (which itself is private API in JDK 8). Both of those also subclass private API classes, so there's no reasonable way to change the supplied behavior. You'd need to register an event handler somehow with each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the Scene to do it:

```
scene.getAccelerators().put(
    KeyCombination.valueOf("Enter"), () -> {
        Node focusOwner = scene.getFocusOwner();
        if (focusOwner instanceof Button) {
            ((Button) focusOwner).fire();
        }
    });
```

You can also do it with an event handler:

```
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        Node focusOwner = scene.getFocusOwner();
        if (focusOwner instanceof Button) {
            ((Button) focusOwner).fire();
        }
    }
});
```

Normally I’d agree with James_D that changing the standard behavior of buttons is not a good idea, but I’m finding that all GTK applications allow Enter to trigger a button press, as does Firefox as you’ve mentioned.

Comment: I used your second solution. It works. The only problem that when I press Space on button, button color changes (as it were pressed), but when I press enter button color doesn't change. Is it possible to make button color react to Enter press?

Comment: That is a bug which has been fixed in Java 9.  Java 9 will be released on Sept. 21 of this year (one week from today).